# Running ServiceBus in windows docker container

Tags: powershell, docker, servicebus

The main goal is to run the ServiceBus in a docker container for windows.

**Output of docker version:**

```
Client:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   092cba3
 Built:        Wed Feb  8 08:47:51 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   092cba3
 Built:        Wed Feb  8 08:47:51 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

**Dockerfile content:**

```
# Is used as sql server local storage for servicebus
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express

COPY install/ /install

# WebPlatform Installer http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/F/F/CFF3A0B8-99D4-41A2-AE1A-496C08BEB904/WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi 
RUN msiexec /i install\WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi /qn

# Install servicebus using webpicmd offline installation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn441408.aspx#BMK_SBConfig1616
RUN WebpiCmd /Install /Products:ServiceBus_1_1 /AcceptEula /SuppressReboot /xml:c:\install\SBWebPICache\feeds\latest\webproductlist.xml
```

### Steps to reproduce:

**1. Build image with parameters:**

`docker build --no-cache -t servicebus $folder`

```
...
Verifying successful installation...    
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64) True    
Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 RTM True    
Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 CU1 True    
Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1 True
Windows Azure Pack: Update for Service Bus 1.1 - .NET Framework 4.6 Compatibility (KB3086798) True
Install of Products: SUCCESS
```

Servicebus installed successfully as expected

**2. Run container with parameters:**

`docker run -it --rm --isolation hyperv servicebus powershell`

**3. Create new servicebus farm:**

`New-SBFarm -SBFarmDBConnectionString 'data source=.; integrated security=true' -CertificateAutoGenerationKey (ConvertTo-SecureString -string "P@assword" -force -AsPlainText)`

Failed with error:

```
New-SBFarm : The Server service is not started.
```

Starting service manually:

```
Start-Service : Service 'Server (LanmanServer)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service LanmanServer on computer '.'
```

Found that service depends on ‘srvnet’ that fails to start on Windows 10 (10.0.14393) using hyper-v isolation:

```
Start-Service : Failed to start service 'srvnet (srvnet)'.
```

But successfully starts on Windows Server 2016 (10.0.14393) using process isolation. However, even with srvnet service running and File-Services installed it's still not working. Server *lanmanserver* service can not be started

**Question:**
Are any possibilities to make *lanmanserver* working inside windows container? Or any other ways to create servicebus farm?